# how to create a tags in azure disk using python?

Tags: python, azure

I want to add or create a new tag in Azure Disk using python but not able to do anyone please help me with python sdk/code for this.

```
for disk in compute_client.disks.list():
   if disk.as_dict()["name"] == "test_disk_rohit":
      tags = target_disk.tags["DetachedTime"] = datetime.now()
      compute_client.disks.begin_create_or_update(resrc,disk.as_dict()["name"],disk)
```

This is what I tried to add/create a new tag for my azure disk called "test_disk_rohit".
Anyone help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **`begin_create_or_update`** you can use **`create_or_update`**.

I have followed the below code snippet I can be able to create/update the tags in desk

```py
AZURE_TENANT_ID= '<Tenent ID>'
AZURE_CLIENT_ID='<Client ID>'
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='<Client Secret>'
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID='<Sub_ID>'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,tenant=AZURE_TENANT_ID)  

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials,AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

Diskdetails = compute_client.disks.create_or_update(
    '<ResourceGroupName>',
    '<Disk Name>',
    {
        'location': 'eastasia',
        'creation_data': {
            'create_option': DiskCreateOption.copy,
            'source_resource_id': <Source Resource ID>

},
        "tags": {
            "tagtest": "testtagGanesh"
        },
    }
)

disk_resource = Diskdetails.result()
#get Disk details
disk = compute_client.disks.get('<ResourceGroupName>','<Disk Name>')

print(disk.sku)
```

[image]